# rational function of affine algebraic variety that agrees on open subset are equal

Tags: algebraic-geometry

So this is the definition I am using:
[image]

[image]

and I want to show the following:
[image]

So I have been stuck on this because I think I want to show that if we have two different rational functions, that I can find a point in $W$ such that they have the same representatives because if they have one representative in common, then that would imply they are in the same equivalence class, but I've been stuck.

Comment: do you know that open any open subset is dense?

Answer (score 0):

If you cross multiply and move everything to one side, you can reduce this to a question about regular functions: if $f$ is a regular function and $f=0$ on a non-empty open set $U\subset X$, then $f=0$ on $X$. But every non-empty subset of an irreducible space is dense! Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hi , thank you for the reply. So I have already done that. So we get fg'=f'g on the whole of X and thus f/g=f/g' on the intersection of the sets where g and g' do not vanish. So I thought I was suppose to show these two elements are in the fact the same elements in k(X). So while they are equal as functions, I am not sure how to show that the representatives are also equal...namely that f=f' and g=g'.

Comment: When we define the field of fractions in a domain $A$, we declare two fractions $a/b$ and $a'/b'$ to be equal precisely when $ab'=ba'$ in $A$. If we needed to have $a=a'$ and $b=b'$, then we would run into trouble, e.g. $1/1\neq 2/2$.